# Perl script to print out all the lines containing a keyword and the line below it

Tags: perl, text

I need to write a perl script to search for a keyword in a large file and then print all the lines containing the keyword plus the line below each keyword to a new file.

In the original file, there are multiple lines (the exact number varies) below each keyword-containing line. I already have a script that makes the variable number of lines to equal 1. I need this functionality to remain in the script and build upon it.

I found out that I could use grep to extract the lines, but this requires running the script I already have first and then using the grep command. I'd really need to have these functions to be combined into one.

Any help is much appreaciated!

Here is the script I have so far:

```
use strict;
open (FILE, $ARGV[0]) or die ("Cannot open file");
my $name;
my $sequence;
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    chomp ($line);
    if (substr ($line, 0, 1) eq ">") {
            if ($sequence ne "") {
                    printf if / ("%s\n%s\n", $name, $sequence);
            }
            $name = $line;
            $sequence = "";
    } else {
    $sequence .= $line;
}
}
if ($sequence ne "") {
    printf ("%s\n%s\n", $name, $sequence);
}
```

And an example of the original file:

> sp|Q6GZX4|001R_FRG3G Putative transcription factor 001R OS=Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) GN=FV3-001R PE=4 SV=1
>   MAFSAEDVLKEYDRRRRMEALLLSLYYPNDRKLLDYKEWSPPRVQVECPKAPVEWNNPPSEKGLIVGHFSGIKYKGEKAQASEVDVNKMCCWVSKFKDAMRRYQGIQTCKIPGKVLSDLDAKIKAYNLTVEGVEGFVRYSRVTKQHVAAFLKELRHSKQYENVNLIHYILTDKRVDIQHLEKDLVKDFKALVESAHRMRQGHMINVKYILYQLLKKHGHGPDGPDILTVKTGSKGVLYDDSFRKIYTDLGW

In this example, the keyword would be "FRG3G". The keyword is always in the same place, the characters before it vary, but the structure is the same.

Comment: By "the keyword is always in the same place", do you mean it always begins on the 16th character in the line? Or do you mean that it is always in the 3rd pipe-delimited field, following the first underscore? Or something else altogether?

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply!
Both conditions you mentioned apply in this case (the keyword always begins on the 16th character in the line and it is always in the 3rd pipe-delimited field, following the first underscore)
Sorry for my ambiguity.

Comment: Hmm, but when the number of lines below the keyword varies, I can't use grep to extract keyword-containing line + the line below.
For example, in the original file, when the keyword is "human", the number of lines below each "human" could be 1-5.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 line to print after the keyword line, you can just remember if you found the keyword and then print the line like this:

```
my $matched = 0;
while (<FILE>) {
    print if ($matched);
    if (m/$keyword/) {
        print;
        matched = 1;
    }
    else {
        matched = 0;
    }
}
```

If you can detect the end of the lines you want to print somehow, you can adjust the code above instead of just hard-coding it to print 1 line.

Redirect to a new file as needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to add this to my existing code so that it'll work.